# Plotting gridded data (without lat lon infotrmation) to create subplots using Cartopy

Tags: python-xarray, subplot, cartopy

Can someone tell me how can i use gridded data of 5km resolution, to plot radar reflectivity? the reflectivity REF (time, z, y, x) is function of x, y, z instead of lat and lon. the x extent is -250 kms to 250kms (west to east) originating from the radar location(same for north south). is it possible to use cartopyfeatures to plot 250kms around the radar location and simulataneouly the the radar reflectivity(dBZ)???

```
import pyproj
import numpy as np

center_lat = 26.820560455322266
center_lon = 75.81861114501953
x_values = xg['x']
y_values = xg['y']

# Define the projection
proj = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', lat_0=center_lat, lon_0=center_lon)

# Convert x and y values to latitude and longitude
lon_values, lat_values = proj(x_values, y_values, inverse=True)

# Calculate the latitude-longitude extent
lat_min, lat_max = np.min(lat_values), np.max(lat_values)
lon_min, lon_max = np.min(lon_values), np.max(lon_values)

# Define the latitude-longitude extent
lat_lon_extent = [lat_min, lat_max, lon_min, lon_max]
print(lat_lon_extent)
lats = lat_values
lons = lon_values

import pyart
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import glob
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as feat
import numpy as np

cff = glob.glob("C:/Users/shrey/RADAR_DATA/RADAR_DATA_JAIPUR/JPR220524IMD-B/output/outgrid_new/grid_new*nc")
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

for files in cff[:]:
    read_files = pyart.io.read_grid(files)
    xg_files = read_files.to_xarray()
    # Select the desired z heights for plotting
    z_heights = [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000]
    # Calculate the number of subplots
    num_subplots = len(z_heights)
    # Calculate the number of rows and columns for the subplots
    num_rows = num_subplots // 2  # Integer division
    num_cols = 2

    # Create a figure and subplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_rows, ncols=num_cols, figsize=(12, 12))
    # Flatten the axes array to easily access individual subplots
    axes = axes.flatten()

    # Loop over the z heights and plot on the respective subplots
    for i, z_height in enumerate(z_heights):
        ax = axes[i]  # Get the current subplot

        # Select the reflectivity data at the current z height
        reflectivity = xg_files['REF'].sel(z=z_height, method='nearest')

        # Get the longitude and latitude values
        lon = lons
        lat = lats

        # Plot the reflectivity using plt.pcolormesh
        im = ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, reflectivity, vmin=0, vmax=60, cmap='rainbow', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

        # Set the title for the current subplot
        ax.set_title(f"Reflectivity at z = {z_height} m")

        # Add coastline and states to the current subplot
        ax.add_feature(feat.STATES, linewidth=0.5)
        ax.add_feature(feat.BORDERS, linewidth=1)

    # Adjust spacing between subplots
    fig.suptitle(f"File: {files.split('_')[-1]}", fontsize=16)
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Add colorbar
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.8)
    cbar.set_label('Reflectivity (dBZ)')

    # Show the plot
    plt.show()
```

i have used pyproj to convert the distance extent to lat lon extent. unfortuantely the output plot shows a good cartopy features but unable to give the reflectivity data plot over it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tGai.png)

Comment: I doubt you used this code yourself? Initializing the axes without a projection will result in a plain Matplotlib Axes, without methods like `ax.add_feature`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am relatively new to this cartopy and plotting. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: That's fine, but it's going to be really hard to help you with this without having some sample data. Did you try running the code you shared? As said, it should crash on `ax.add_feature` because you don't create the axes with a Cartopy projection.

Comment: I did run, it came out wrong . actually i have no issues plotting the reflectivity, with all the colormap. but when it is with the cartopy, only the catopy features are coming, and  the reflectivity plot is not coming on top of it.

Comment: i uploaded a sample image for example on the top, just below the program, in case it comes to be of any help.

Comment: As said, you don't specify the Cartopy projection when creating the axes. So I still doubt this code can run, it shouldn't have the `ax.add_feature` method, which should cause a crash. It's also likely that that's where the issue is, it almost always a projection/conversion thing. Or perhaps your `reflectivity` object, it might be better to force that to be a Numpy array. But I can't tell without seeing the data, or the actual code you used. I'm guessing.